# Pycaret plot_model not properly

Tags: python, pycaret

I got this error code when i try to use plot_model()

```
---> 16 from scipy.fftpack.helper import _init_nd_shape_and_axes_sorted
     17 from numpy import (allclose, angle, arange, argsort, array, asarray,
     18                    atleast_1d, atleast_2d, cast, dot, exp, expand_dims,

ImportError: cannot import name '_init_nd_shape_and_axes_sorted' from 'scipy.fftpack.helper'
```

Any solutions?

This lib will be developed next version? I see more errors than before like Jinja2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this with the newly released version (3.0.0.rc2). The Jinga insall should be resolved in this release.

`pip install -U --pre pycaret`

Regarding your actual error, can you provide the reproducible example of what caused the issue?

Comment: on my colab when I'm install pycaret with 
`!pip install -U --pre pycaret`
and from pycaret.regression import * I got an error
`ImportError: scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx does not export expected C variable _export_expit`

Comment: Can you open a GitHub issue? It will guide you through the steps and ask for relevant information to reproduce the problem and then debug it. Without this information, it is hard to provide an answer to this question. https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/new/choose